# Transfer learning with sklearn

Tags: python, tensorflow

how to copy weights of a RandomForestRegressor to another model ? to improve the model's accuracy
`

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33)  
model = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100,max_features=3, random_state=42)
model.fit(X_train,y_train)`
```

I have to copy weights of this trained model to another random forest regressor to improve predictions , how do i do that ?

Comment: Complete guidelines on Transfer learning using Tensorflow is discussed [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning). Thanks!